# Python webscraping - search Google result for EAN (number with 13 letters)

Tags: python, python-requests-html

I have a tool with thich code i can already display google search results text:

```
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ean%22+%22Rowenta%20X-Plorer%20Serie%2075%20RR7687%22&client=firefox-b-d&ei=8W5cYdi-Kc-ckgW-54LIDA&ved=0ahUKEwiY-_zeyrPzAhVPjqQKHb6zAMkQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=%22ean%22+%22Rowenta%20X-Plorer%20Serie%2075%20RR7687%22"
            f = s.get(url)
            eanfield = f.html.xpath(
                '//*[@id="center_col"]', first=True)
            ean = eanfield.text
```

I want to filter out the EAN that usually gets displayed in the Search results when searching "ean" " title of product  "

The Ean is a number with 13 letters in exact, thats why i need to filter out only a number with a certain length from the text result. How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add an actual url to work with?

Comment: Use xpath `//*[@id="center_col"]//span[contains(., 'EAN')]` to get specific element.
then use regular expression on result if found, like:
`re.search(r'EAN[:\s]\s?(\d+)', txt_found).group(1)`

Comment: its now like this: https://pastebin.com/s4ihUthk still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
efs = f.html.xpath('//span[em["EAN"]]')
for ef in efs:
    print(ef.text.split("EAN: ")[1][:13])
```

output:

```
3221616001114
3221616001220
3221616001114
3221616001114
8710103792925
7332543577989
3221614006807
3221614003868
```

Comment: Now it gives me this error: https://pastebin.com/wrCp6VQp (code also in pastebin)